# Unable to access Multiselect Values in Ruby on Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement a multi-select for a many to many relationship in Ruby on Rails, however I'm unable to access the array of strings representing the selected User Ids in the user_ids field.

The following is my `project_params` after clicking update

```
"project"=>{"name"=>"Project Name", 
"client"=>"Client X", "project_url"=>""}, 
"user_ids"=>["2", "3", "4", "5"], "commit"=>"Update Project", "id"=>"1"}
```

The following is my `ProjectsController` code

```
 def update
    puts project_params[:user_ids=>[]]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
 end
 def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:id, :name, :client, :project_url,  :user_ids => [])
 end
```

The line `puts project_params[:user_ids=>[]]` prints a blank line. I've also tried `puts project_params[:user_ids]` and `puts project_params[:user_ids[]]` - none of which work

The following is my `_form.html.erb` Code

```
 <%= select_tag "user_ids",
     options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, "id", "name", @project.user),
     { :multiple => true, :size =>10}
 %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select tag will use the first argument as the key. Hence the values is located on:

```
params[:user_ids]
```

or if you are using form builder

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
 <%= f.select :user_ids,
     options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, "id", "name", @project.user),
     { :multiple => true, :size =>10}
 %>
<% end %>
```

then it will be available in `project_params`

Comment: Ahh that was dumb of me... using the wrong params :/ Thanks for your help!